# How to tell the framework to copy static files to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files when building the website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5

I have been bothered by a very troubling issue regarding an asp.net project (MVC5 to be more specific)  for the last 2 days. I tried to search the internet for a solution, only to discover the cause which I already know.

In my case i'm having a MVC5 project referencing a third party's DLL which consumes a c++ DLL, and 2 other text configuration files, apparently these files has to reside in the same folder with the third party's DLL. after compiling all the necessary files (the 3rd party's DLL and all of its dependencies) are then correctly copied to the bin folder. However, when browsing to the site hosted by IIS7.5, the framework then only takes the 3 party's DLL to the \Temporary ASP.NET folder, which cause a lot of run-time errors when instructions from the DLL are executed by the process.

How can I produce some way of configuration to show the Framework these dependencies in order to gain the behavior I'm expecting ?

Comment: Which version of visual studio are you using?